# System.NullReferenceException Xamarin Android arrayAdapter

Tags: android, xamarin, android-arrayadapter

initialize `ArrayAdapter` by class `MainActivity`, set it in `OnCreate` and still in method UpdateAdapter(BluetoothDevice device) I get error: `System.NullReferenceException Object Reference not set to an instance of object`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/khPos.jpg

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        ListView mainlist;
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();
        public ArrayAdapter<string> arrayAdapter; ...

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            mainlist = (ListView)FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, lista);
            mainlist.Adapter = arrayAdapter;
```

...

```
        skanujbtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var receiver_ = new BluetoothDeviceReceiver();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound);
            RegisterReceiver(receiver_, filter);
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.IsDiscovering) bluetoothAdapter.StartDiscovery();}

        public void UpdateAdapter(BluetoothDevice device)
        {
            lista.Add(device.Name);
            arrayAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Other class

```
public class BluetoothDeviceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var action = intent.Action;
        if (action != BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
        {
            return;
        }
    // Get the device
    var device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);

    if (device.BondState != Bond.Bonded)
    {
        MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
        obj.UpdateAdapter(device);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code it is not telling much, you have to share where you use that method?

Here are my guesses:

**Guess1:**

Question: What is the device object initialised on?

Probably device object you are receiving in the method is null from what I can see:
If you have class something like this

```
public class BluetoothDevice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You need to initalize it at least to one object before it is propagated to the method

```
 BluetoothDevice device = new BluetoothDevice()
 {
      Name = "SomeBluetoothDevice"
 };
```

**Guess2:**

You are invoking the UpdateAdapter() method before the initialization of the Adapter

*EDIT:*

Here is the issue you are creating new instance from MainActivity

```
if (device.BondState != Bond.Bonded)
    {
        **MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();**
        obj.UpdateAdapter(device);

    }
```

that way it will create a new instance of the activity but it won't invoke the OnCreate method because that is not how Activities are created you can create by intent of type of

Anyway here is how can you fix the isssue:
Use the already existing instance from the Activity in the BluetoothDeviceReceiver add this code:

```
public class BluetoothDeviceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        MainActivity mainActivity;
        public BluetoothDeviceReceiver(MainActivity mainActivity)
        {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            mainActivity.UpdateAdapter(device);
        }
    }
```

In the MainActivity:

```
 skanujbtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
 {
            var receiver_ = new BluetoothDeviceReceiver(this);
...
 }
```

Comment: when i was testing its getting correctly the name, but i guess the problem is with new MainActivity()? im not sure how  i can get to method UpdateAdapter and pass through argument device

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Check the one I have provided bellow EDIT:..